# Purpose of replacing .php with .html extension through .htaccess file

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I was reading a little about .htaccess file and I found that it's possible to change `.php` in the url to `.html`

But I do not understand what the point of doing it is or what it tries to achieve.

Please note that i'm a beginner with .htaccess also I've searched for that on Google but I didn't found what i'm looking for

Comment: it's for SEO related purposes :) or at least it was when I first started dev

Comment: @blabla Not necessarily, the dynamic ones, using `?id=23` for example are less likely to be indexed due to it being dynamic pages.

Comment: I don't buy this SEO reason at all, to think that google will prefer file extension in the URLs over  _high quality content_ sound ridiculous (To me, at least). I can also tell you that I had no problem with SEO when using PHP extensions in the past so I don't think you need to bother with that particular reason too much.  You can read about some other, more logic reasons [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/56263/15314), but this question eventually is primarily opinion based

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an ever ongoing battle between seo friendly url's and not. It all depends on the very purpose of your site. If for an example you have a script with dynamic pages like search script or generator of some type (very broad , right ? ;) ) then if your url looks like this:
   domain.tld/products?id=183
Rather than
   domain.tld/products|183.html
then I don't think there is any better than .php, it's still dynamic and SE will discover that but if you have blog then you might consider a proper wording in url instead of id's. I can think of only one reason apart from what SE' see. What your viewer/surfer sees. I think if he quickly glance at domain.tld/date/rather-simple-title then he might be more interested than in id=183. Now if the url has extension domain.tld/date/rather-simple-title.php or domain.tld/date/rather-simple-title.html in my humble opinion there's no impact on either SE or your website visitor. 
Pure theory and rather opinion based conversation here, like the question.